# RabbitMQ gives an error when running the examples given by pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying to run some examples which were provided by pika library for RabbitMQ and I get an error.

The first time when I try to run the publisher or consumer it will create an exchange, and a queue and everything works fine. Second time when I try to run the example I get:

```
Received remote Channel.Close (406): "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for exchange '...' in vhost '/': received 'true' but current is 'false'" on <Channel number=1 OPEN conn=<AsyncioConnection OPEN transport=<pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils._AsyncPlaintextTransport object at 0x103fadac0> params=<URLParameters host=... port=... virtual_host=/ ssl=False>>>
```

When the Queue is created everything is fine, if the Queue exists already and it has the argument (durable = True) I have this error.

I have tried to modify this line from example but is still the same result:

```
self._channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name,
                                callback=self.on_queue_declareok,
                                durable=True)
```

The examples which I am trying to run are:
https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/main/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.py
and
https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/main/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.py

Comment: Hello, I maintain Pika. I can't reproduce what you report - stopping and re-starting both examples multiple times works fine. Please re-try with a fresh RabbitMQ installation. If you continue to have issues, start a discussion here - https://github.com/pika/pika/discussions

Comment: Thank you, I have tried with everything fresh and it seems that it worked. It is quite strange, I tried two times and I had the same issue, I tried now and it works. Cannot explain what was changed. Thanks anyway.